# How to handle default value as partial parameters in dust.js?

Tags: template-engine, dust.js

I actually made a simple dust partial and I would like to give it some parameters with default value. Not very easy to explain but here is a simple example:

---

**Partials**

partials/hello.dust

```
{?label}{label}{:else}Hello{/label}: 
<span>{?name}{name}{:else}World{/name}</span>
```

partials/hello2.dust

```
{>"partials/hello"/} and 
{>"partials/hello" label="{label2}" name="{name2}"/}</div>
```

---

**Examples of how it should work**

test_0.dust

```
{>"partials/hello2" label="Peter" name="Parker" label2="Clark" name2="Kent"/}
```

Returns: "Peter:Parker and Clark:Kent"

test_1.dust

```
{>"partials/hello2" label2="Clark" name2="Kent"/}
```

Returns: "Hello:World and Clark:Kent"

test_2.dust

```
{>"partials/hello2" label="Peter" name="Parker"/}
```

Returns: "Peter:Parker and Hello:World"

test_3.dust

```
{>"partials/hello2"/}
```

Returns: "Hello:World and Hello:World"

---

In partials/hello.dust, if label & name variables are not defined, they are replaced with default values (respectively "Hello" and "World")

So here, test_0.dust and test_1.dust will work since I provide label2 and name2 parameters.

In partials/hello2.dust, I don't know if this is possible to do this an elegant way but I would like a different default value for label2 and name2 variables so it is not mandatory to provide them either ("Hello2" and "World2" for example).

One solution I can think of would be to handle all possible combinations in hello2.dust including the partial accordingly (i.e. label2 empty and name2 empty, label2 empty and name2 not empty, label2 not empty and name2 empty, label2 not empty and name2 not empty) but it can be pretty painful and ugly as you can see.

To be clear I would like to be able to do something like this:

partials/hello2.dust

```
{>"partials/hello"/}
{>"partials/hello" label="{?label2}{label2}{:else}Hello2{/label2}" name="{?name2}{name2}{:else}World2{/name2}"/}
```

---

---

**SOLUTION**

In case it would help someone, I finally made my own dust helper:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (dust) {
    dust.helpers.default = function (chunk, ctx, bodies, params) {
        var resData, paramVals = {}, saveData = chunk.data;

        var localCtx = ctx;
        if (params) {
            localCtx = ctx.push(params);
        }
        for (var key in bodies) {
            if (key !== 'block') {
                chunk.data = [];
                resData = bodies[key](chunk, localCtx).data.join('');
                if (typeof ctx.get(key) === 'undefined') {
                    paramVals[key] = resData;
                }
            }
        }
        chunk.data = saveData;
        return bodies.block(chunk, localCtx.push(paramVals));
    };
};
```

So, it can be used like this:

```
{@default}
{>"partials/mypartialusingname1"/}
hello {name1} & {name2} 
{:name1}Chuck Norris
{:name2}Walter White
{/default}
```

Then, if name1 and name2 does not exist in the current context it is replaced by some default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dust does not include a facility for setting default values for a context.

This would be a job for a Dust helper. A naïve version of this helper might look like this:

### Template

```
{@defaultParam key="hello" value="moo"/}
{@defaultParam key="world" value="world"/}
{hello} {world}
```

### Context

```
{
    "hello": "hello"
}
```

### Helper

```
dust.helpers.defaultParam = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var key = params.key,
      value = params.value;

  if(typeof context.get(key) === 'undefined') {
    context.global[key] = value;
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought I may have missed something with the dust syntax itself, but a helper is great. Just one question, why naive? The approach looks good enough to just want to set a simple value.

Comment: Yep, it will work for setting a simple value, I just didn't want to sell it to you as the end-all solution. For example, this helper can't set full objects. Also, it's setting into the global context, so you couldn't have two partials that used the same default param name (you'd need to do something like look into the parent's context and set stuff there instead). But the functionality exists if you want to make it more robust!

Comment: yep, the @default helper I've made works pretty well without setting the global context actually.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem by creating a similar helper. Using key value attributes in a single `@defaults` helper declaration.

### Parent template

```
<!-- Standard partial include -->
{>"components/module-promo" /}

<!-- Partial include with overrides -->
{>"components/module-promo" title="Custom title override" caption="Custom caption" /}
```

### Partial

```
{@defaults
    title="Module title"
    caption="Module caption ipsum dolor sit amet."
/}

<article>
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{caption}</p>
</article>
```

### Helper

```
dust.helpers.defaults = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    for (var key in params) {
        context.global[key] = params[key];
    }
    return chunk;
};
```

(Remember to return the `chunk` from the helper function.)

This works really well for synchronous template rendering. We store our values on `context.global`, and add/modify them as the partials compile. This means `global` is mutated, but we do avoid issues with multiple partials using the same parameter names.

The approach would run into trouble if attempting to stream/async the template renders. Maybe someone could elaborate on the best way to store partial-specific context values to improve this?